# add onto a line based on the lines content

Tags: regex, plsql, replace

I want to use regular expression to add onto a line based on the lines content.

The line looks like this:

```
decode((SOMETHING_UNIQUE,'','','') OBJECT
```

and I want it to look like this

```
decode((SOMETHING_UNIQUE,'','','') OBJECT,decode((SOMETHING_UNIQUE,'','','') SUMMARY
```

So I tried this but it does work:

```
FIND: decode((\w+),'','','') OBJECT
REPLACE: decode((\1,'','','') OBJECT,decode((\1,'','','') SUMMARY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues.

1. You need to escape your `(` and `)` characters that are straight textual matches.

   `decode\((\w+),'','',''\) OBJECT`
2. In your replace, you are adding an extra `(` before the pattern you are matching.

   It should be `decode(\1,` instead of `decode((\1,`

With my tests I had to use `$1` instead of `\1`, but that is just because of the regex engine.

[Test Link](http://regexr.com?3568p)

Comment: Yes I did and it can't find it. PS After the two decode there is a \ but it doesn't show up in the above comment

Comment: @user2367789 okay, I added a link to the working regex, just in case.